# How to use laravel auto presenter's decoratable interface?

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel auto presenter. While using single model, it is working properly but I want to use it with function - how do I do that?

According to the documentation,

> the decoratable interface is used to allow the model's relations to be
>   decorated.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "use it with function"?

Comment: i mean eager loading